# Rails: send chunks to client without wait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video-streaming

I want to stream remote data (video) to a client as the chunks come in to my rails server, make my rails server act like a reverse proxy.
Using Rails 7.0.4 on Ruby 3.2.2

I have build something with `ActionController::Live` that "works", but it reads all chunks of the remote file/stream first, so there is a long client wait if the file is big. According to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.8/classes/ActionController/Live.html) it is able to stream data to the client as it’s written, but it reads all data first before writing. I see this from my debug output for every 1000 chunks, it fills up before the client gets any data. How can i serve to client passing chunks as the come in?

This is the code, that reads all chunks from the remote source first, before passing to the client:

```
class SocketController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live
  def test
    uri = URI('https://somefile')
    i = 0
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4'
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
      http.request request do |remote_response|
        remote_response.read_body do |chunk|
          i += 1
          puts i if i % 1000 == 0
          response.stream.write chunk
        end
      end
    end
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rack 2.2 broke streaming capabilities of `ActionController::Live` according to https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1619

Update to Rails 7.1 with Rack 3 fixes this.

For Rack 2.2.x adding `response.headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate` in the controller method *or* adding `config.middleware.delete Rack::ETag` in `application.rb` helps.

Source: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1619#issuecomment-848460528